# How to print web scrapping results to a file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, maven, sorting, selenium-webdriver

I want to save program results to file. Currently I'm printing them to console. How would I do it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Dejan Kostov\\IdeaProjects\\MavenSigmaSpeakers1\\src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver-74.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://sigma.world/eurasia/speakers/");

    String[] expected = {"Gary Vaynerchuk", "John Lee", "Jordan Belfort", "Clinton Sparks", "Johnny Walker", "Dr. Sara Al Madani", "VESA", "Irina S. Litchfield", "Cal Evans", "Dr Jane Thomason", "Gordon Einstein", "Jimmy Nguyen", "Robert Dowling", "Aideen Shortt", "Dustin Plantholt", "Andres Meneses", "Arvin Khamseh", "Agne Linge", "Joshua Ellul", "Mike Prasad", "Paweł Łaskarzewski", "Obediah Ayton", "Jorge Sebastiao", "Wesley Ellul", "Nikita Sachdev", "Joseph F Borg", "Zack Ritchie", "Francisco Fernandez", "Gabriel Laender", "Reem Al Mosabbeh", "Cannelle Maricaux", "Onur Altan Tan", "Jitendra Vaswani", "Marco Funk", "James Bowater", "Susan Oh", "Laura K. Inamedinova", "Isabella Händel", "Tejinder Kumar", "Gustavo Montero", "Adel Bhurtun", "Vas Modinos", "Alexander Fazel", "Alexander Mihailovski", "Marc Taverner", "Pavlina Papalouka", "Emma Todd", "Cordelia Morgan Cooper", "Nick Spanos", "John Murillo", "Alex Tsepaev", "Anna Tutova", "H.E. Mr. Zulfiquar Ghadiyali", "Shafeeq Qureshi", "Bailey Dodds", "Joan de Ramón Brunet", "Amir Student", "Amna Usman Chaudhry", "Ayesha Mubarak Ali", "Nadia Dvoinos", "Mario Nawfal", "Alex J.", "Paula Tavangar", "Cinderella Amar", "Joel Michael", "Kevin Imani", "José. F. Pereira", "Paula Hajduczenia", "Dr Andreas Mathikolonis", "Alena Zharkovskaya", "Edward Condrat", "Wadih Al Sayah", "Aravind Swaminathan","Luca Tagliaferro"};

    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h3"));

    System.out.println("Number of elements with tag h3 : " + elements.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        WebElement element = elements.get(i);
        System.out.println(i + " : " + element.getText());
        if (element.getText().equals(expected[i])) {
            System.out.println("Strings are equal");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Strings are NOT equal");
    

                    driver.quit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code would write the console output to a specified file:

```
PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new File("C:\\Users\\username\\consoleOutput.txt"));
System.setOut(printStream);
```

Add the above 2 lines to your code anywhere before you start printing.